# SAS subsetting based on a macro variable

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

I have created a macro variable which is the datetime at the time the program is run less one month, formatted to datetime20:

```
%let startDate = %sysfunc(intnx(dtmonth, %sysfunc(datetime()), -1), datetime20.);
```

This part works correctly (if I run it right now, it returns 01JUL2015:00:00:00), but what I want to do is subset a dataset based on this date in a PROC SQL statement.  Basically I want to keep everything where the date occurs in the last month.  My code is:

```
proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= &startDate.;
quit;
```

The column "date" and the variable "startDate" are both of type 'datetime20', but it is still throwing an error:

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, 
              <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, EXCEPT, GE, GET, GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, INTERSECT, 
              LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, OR, ORDER, OUTER, UNION, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.

I don't know why it is throwing this error.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro processor is a code generator so your code is generating

```
proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= 01JUL2015:00:00:00;
quit;
```

This isn't valid SAS code. 
You can either use the SAS datetime number rather than convert/format it to a datetime value, or create a date literal for comparison. 
To create a date literal, enclose the macro variable in quotes and end it with dt to indicate a datetime value.

```
proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= "01JUL2015:00:00:00"dt;
quit;
```

To create a SAS datetime numeric value, remove the format in the  %sysfunc().

```
%let startDate = %sysfunc(intnx(dtmonth, %sysfunc(datetime()), -1));

proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= &startDate.;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks. Answers are very similar, whats the protocol in such a situation?

Comment: @Reeza Doesn't really matter, I could delete mine or just leave it.  Doesn't hurt anything to leave it in the event my explanation is more to someone's taste, I generally figure.

Comment: Even though both approaches work, my preference would be to drop the format from sysfunc.  It's easier to work with raw datetime values than literals, especially if further manipulation of the value is done later in the program.  Good that you mentioned both alternatives though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are formatting the result - don't do that.  Remember, macro variables are just creating text, they're not actual variables - they don't have concepts like "formats" (where a regular SAS variable is able to be the numeric date value AND the "pretty" formatted text).

```
1    %let startDate = %sysfunc(intnx(dtmonth, %sysfunc(datetime()), -1), datetime20.);
2    %put &=startdate.;
STARTDATE=01JUL2015:00:00:00
```

So:

```
proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= 01JUL2015:00:00:00;
quit;
```

That's illegal, because that's not a datetime value, it's a nice pretty human readable datetime that SQL/SAS looks at and doesn't know what to do with.

You can either drop the format bit from the `%sysfunc`, or add `"..."dt` around it to make it a datetime constant.

```
data existing_table;
  do date=datetime()-86400*50 to datetime() by 86400;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
create table work.last_month as
select * from work.existing_table
where date >= "&startdate."dt;
quit;
```